# Swift お絵かきアプリの消しゴム

Tags: ios, swift

こちらの記事を参考にお絵かきのアプリを作ってみたのですが、
書いた線を消しゴムで、消す方法はあるでしょうか？

http://tono-n-chi.com/blog/2015/03/ios-touch-drawing-in-swift/

こちらの記事と違う点として、UIImageViewを2枚重ねて、
奥側のUIImageViewに写真を設定し、手前のUIImageViewに線を
描画するようにしています。

背景は白であれば、self.drawColor = UIColor.WhiteColor()を
設定して、消したい線をなぞれば、消しているようなイメージになりますが、
背景の写真があるので、白い線が描画されてしまいます。

self.drawColor = UIColor.ClearColor()を設定して、
線をなぞってみましたが、何も変化がありませんでした。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ブレンドモードを指定して描画すると色をクリアできますよ。

```
bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
// addLineToPointなど...
bezierPath.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeClear, alpha: 0)
```

Comment: 教えていただいたやり方でブレンドモードを指定して、
描画色にも、UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)を指定することで実現できました。
ありがとうございます。